# ffmpeg - extract single frame -- DEINTERLACED

Tags: ffmpeg, video

i want to extract the first image from every second of video. i have a command line, based on the video's timecode, that works correctly when the video is progressive, but not when interlaced (only the first field is output in that case, creating a half-height image). i've tried various combinations of `bwdif` with `select` but the filter chains i create either cause errors or still return a half-sized image. can someone help me with the syntax ?

here is my call w/a filter that works correctly for progressive video source :
`ffmpeg -i $infile -vf "select='if(eq(n\,0),1,floor(t)-floor(prev_selected_t))" -vsync 0 $outfile`

the following still return only half-height images for interlaced source :
`... -vf "bwdif=0,select='if(eq(n\,0),1,floor(t)-floor(prev_selected_t))'"`

`... -vf "bwdif=0,select='between(mod(n\,$ips)\,1\,2)'"`
*-- `$ips` is images per second*

`... -vf "select='between(mod(n\,$ips)\,1\,2)',bwdif=0"`

...and on a related note, is there some truly complete, exhaustive documentation anywhere on the `select` filter ?  (no, i don't consider 'ffmpeg filters' chapter 16.16 exhaustive).

thanks.

Comment: I don't follow what the role of these select statements, but have you tried [`yadif`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#yadif) for deinterlacing?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke yes, both `yadif` and `bwdif` will deinterlace. however, i still need to specify the constraint that i want _only_ the first frame of each second (which is the first two fields of an interlaced video). that is what `select` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out the solution is to use the [tinterlace](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tinterlace) filter first. this causes the half-height frames to be reinterlaced before deinterlacing them as FULL frames with bwdif. the full command line that worked for me was :

```
ffmpeg -i $infile -vf "tinterlace=mode=merge,bwdif=0,select='if(eq(n\,0),1,floor(t)-floor(prev_selected_t))" -vsync
```

many thanks to the responder named Gyan (maybe the same who does ffmpeg development ?) on a thread in stackoverflow.